# Cannot Build Boost 1.47.0 IOStreams on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, ubuntu-16.04

I am working on a legacy project for my company that requires me to use a specific version of boost and that version is 1.47.0. I have downloaded and run:

```
./b2 --toolset=gcc variant=debug
```

and it compiled the majority of the static libraries I needed with the exception of a few. One being libboost_iostreams. I did some research and found that it appeared i was missing some dependencies.

```
whereis bzip2
bzip2: /bin/bzip2 /usr/share/man/man1/bzip2.1.gz

whereis zlib
zlib: /usr/include/zlib.h /usr/share/man/man3/zlib.3.gz
```

However when I attempt to run:

```
./b2 --with-iostreams -s BZIP2_SOURCE=/bin -s ZLIB_SOURCE=/usr/include
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Building the Boost C++ Libraries.
error: Unable to find file or target named
error:     '/bin/libbz2.def'
error: referred from project at 
error:     'libs/iostreams/build'
```

Update:
Linux Version: 16.04

Gcc Version Info:
    gcc -v
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0- 
    6ubuntu1~16.04.9' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs -- 
    enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr -- 
    program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id -- 
    libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix -- 
    libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable- 
    libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new 
    --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable- 
    plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk -- 
    enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre -- 
    enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 -- 
    with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch- 
    directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable- 
    objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with- 
    abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with- 
    tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu -- 
    host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)

Comment: Are you using a 1.47.0 era (2011-Jul-11) version of C++ (gcc 4.6), with a 1.47.0 era version of Ubuntu (10.xx, Lucid Lynx)?

Comment: @Eljay I have added your answer to my question as an update. Does that help?

Comment: It does help.  I've found that trying to use mix-and-match different era's of system headers, C/C++ headers, and Boost library can be a challenge.  You are using 2011 Boost, with 2016 C++, with 2018 Ubuntu.  The C++ & Ubuntu should be okay.  I recommend a Boost that is at least circa 2016 (if not the current), but -- as per your question -- is what you are trying to avoid.